# How to flush to a file in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, io

I have this snippet and a weird thing is going on:

```
out = open("./out.txt","w+")
for line in open("./int.txt","r").readlines():
    for key in dic.keys():
        if line.count(key) > 0:
            line = re.sub(key,dic[key],line)
    print line
    out.write(line)
```

The output to the shell of python is the right one it contains all the lines after the switches according to the `dic{}` while the `out` file contains just about half of the lines?

Comment: Please post your input file, or a subset of it, so we can see what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [the `with` statement](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.3/ref/with.html) to manage the context of your output file handle so that it is closed at the end of the scope (so that when you view it, it is up-to-date). The `for` loop does this for you with your input file.

```
with open("./out.txt", "w+") as out:
    for line in open("./int.txt", "r"):
        for key in dic.keys():
            if key in line:
                line = re.sub(key, dic[key], line)
        print line,
        out.write(line)
```

A few other minor changes:

- `.readlines()` is not required
- `if key in line:` will stop searching for `key` in `line` once it has found the first instance, improving effiency.
- `print line,` will not add another new-line after `line`.

Also consider whether `line = line.replace(key, dic[key])` would suffice, since you're not  searching for a regular expression on the `line`.

Comment: It works, thanks for the tips. My question is why now it works? what with does that regular open doesn't. in java/c# wrapping the code with try catch doesn't change the flow.

Comment: Don't confuse `with` and `try`, `with` is for managing *context* (akin to "scopes" in C-like languages) where `try` is for managing *exceptions*. There's a bit more to it than that, but that's a whole other question!

Answer (score 1):

files don't always get written to disk straight away,  they need flushing
try out.flush() at the end

Comment: Well, a `with` directive would be better. Also, even if you don't flush them manually, at the end of the script (when the stream object is destroyed) it should be flushed automatically anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure what the surround context for his code is, only can see that fragment...